# How to use IntelliJ Groovy interactive console as a repl?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

IntelliJ has a very handy Interactive groovy console which can be used to execute groovy snippets with the Project's classpath. Is it possible to use this console for line by line execution, as in, I write a line and the IDE executes it. Just like the shell works or like the python or ruby repl works.Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
I have looked for config options for the groovy interactive console, but there doesn't seem to be any. Pressing Ctrl+Enter does execute the snippets, but it executes the entire console input, which is not how a repl should work.
There is an option of a groovy shell in intellij docs, but that can only be launched in Groovy projects. I am interested in using groovy to quickly test out my java code in all java projects.

Comment: @GhostCat, I should have been more clear about the options I have looked into. I have edited the question to reflect the same. I have also tried doing it myself for quite some time, and have dropped this question as I believe the question as well as the answer(if any) might be useful to many.  Thanks

Comment: The way I do it in the groovy console is to type in the code I need to check, select chosen lines, then press Ctrl + Enter. The console runs only the selected part of the code.

Comment: For others like me, that weren’t aware of the existence of the _Groovy Console_ (or that don’t have the _Groovy_ plugin installed): you can find it under _Tools_ --> _Groovy Console_.

Answer (score 2):

To use Groovy Console as a REPL, optionally select the lines or expressions that you want to execute and Run the console. This would achieve line-by-line execution. Also, Groovy Console is smart enough to still execute all imports on the top of the console e.g. for your custom code.

Note that after any source code (code-under-test) changes, you have to do 2 things (in my experience with IDEA 2021.1) in order for changes to be recognized by the console:

1. Build the project
2. Stop any previous console runs